# Does 'hiredis' support Redis Sentinel and Redis Cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, hiredis, redisclient

'hiredis' is a minimalistic C client for Redis. Does anyone know if it supports -

- Redis Sentinel (the official high availability solution for Redis) https://redis.io/topics/sentinel
- and Redis Cluster https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

It is not clear from its Github page - https://github.com/redis/hiredis

Answer (score 2):

YES and NO.

Since you can send any command to Redis with `hiredis`, you can get master/slave info from Redis Sentinel, or get the slots info from Redis Cluster. So `hiredis` can work with Redis Sentinel and Redis Cluster.

However, since `hiredis` doesn't have high level API to work with sentinel and cluster, you have to do many work by yourself. If you need high level API, you need to try [other libraries](https://redis.io/clients), for example:

If you're coding with `C`, you can try [hiredis-vip](https://github.com/vipshop/hiredis-vip), which supports Redis Cluster. But I'm not sure if it supports Redis Sentinel.

If you're coding with `C++`, you can try [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus), which supports both Redis Cluster and Redis Sentinel, and has STL-like interfaces.

**Declaimer**: I'm the author of redis-plus-plus.

```
// Example on redis-plus-plus

#include <sw/redis++/redis++.h>

try {
    auto cluster = RedisCluster("tcp://127.0.0.1:7000");
    cluster.set("key", "val");
    auto val = cluster.get("key");
    if (val) cout << *val << endl;
} catch (const Error &e) {
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @for_stack

Comment: hiredis-vip is not maintained anymore. [hiredis-cluster](https://github.com/Nordix/hiredis-cluster) is an actively maintained fork. It supports cluster (not sentinel) and is using hiredis as a dependency.